# How get video stream and save on disk c# Xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, save, video-streaming

I want get stream from a url and save it on the disk. Someone have some advise? I use Xamarin.iOS.

That is the code, but when I try to run it I download the entire page HTML. Any solution.

```
 async Task<bool> SaveToAlbum(string video_url, string directory, string filename)
    {
        var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(directory, filename);
        if (File.Exists(filePath))
            File.Delete(filePath);

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var data = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(video_url);
            if (data != null && data.Length > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, data);

                    //ALAssetsLibrary lib = new ALAssetsLibrary();
                    //lib.WriteVideoToSavedPhotosAlbum(NSUrl.FromFilename(filePath), (t, u) => { });
                    return true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can  get data with HttpClient and save it to photo album , refer to [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/82344/how-to-download-video-and-save-to-camera-roll-xamarin-ios).

Comment: have an example of how use HttpClient for download video?

Comment: ok now I have one problem!! How I can get url of stream and not the HTML of entire page??